# Linq OrderBy but ignore first word if "the"

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the following linq expression to do my ordering but was wondering how do I change this so that it will orderby name but ignore the first word if it is "the"

```
CaseStudies.OrderBy(a => a.Name)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way (if there is always lower-case `the` and no more than one space between words):

```
CaseStudies.OrderBy(a => a.Name.StartsWith("the ") ? a.Name.Substring(4) : a.Name)
```

You can create method with nice descriptive name and move this logic as well as null check and ignore case comparison there:

```
private string RemoveDefiniteArticle(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return s;

    if (s.StartsWith("the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return s.Substring(4).TrimStart();

    return s;
}
```

And use it

```
CaseStudies.OrderBy(a => RemoveDefiniteArticle(a.Name))
```

Comment: Nice and simple, will accept when it lets me, thanks

Comment: @amateur if `the` can be not in lower case (e.g. `The` or `THE`) then consider to use `ToLower()` as Piotr suggested

Comment: Just be careful if `a.Name` could be null.... changing the test to `(a.Name != null && a.Name.StartsWith("the "))` would fix that

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy wouldn't `a.Name.StartsWith(" the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` be better?

Comment: @BobVale completely agree with you on both cases!

Comment: Both this and the other similar answer will give the wrong result (at least I think it's wrong) if someone puts more than one space between "the" and the next word. They would include the leading spaces in the sort. I guess they should use string.Trim() to remove any leading spaces from the Substring()..?

Comment: @MikeGoodwin agree, TrimStart() may be needed, updated answer!

Comment: Of course now I read my comment I realise my typo putting an extra space before `the` that shouldn't be there.  To late to edit it!

Comment: @BobVale I think it's OK :) Core idea is to use ignore case comparison instead of creating lower-case string

Comment: Updated my answer too.

Comment: On reflection, leading spaces BEFORE and after the "the" should probably be trimmed. Why is string handling so fiddly? There always seem to be edge cases...

Comment: That makes what looked like a nice simple solution, look a bit messy. Any better suggestions anyone?

Comment: I suppose. Once you start Trimming you need to use IsNullOrEmpty more often, or IsNullOrWhitespace maybe. Wrapping it up in a single method call makes complete sense, but the method itself gets harder to understand I meant.

Answer (score 2):

There are a surprising number of edge cases here. Suppose your list is

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "The aardvark", "the bear", "The  cat", " dog", "  elephant"};
```

Then the starting point is handling "the" at the start

```
strings.OrderBy(w => w.StartsWith("the ") ? w.Substring(4) : w);
```

Which gives:

```
  elephant 
 dog 
the bear 
The  cat 
The aardvark
```

Ignoring case is better

```
strings.OrderBy(w => w.StartsWith("the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? w.Substring(4) : w);
```

Giving:

```
  elephant 
The  cat 
 dog 
The aardvark 
the bear
```

Handling multiple spaces after the leading "the" is even better, but not perfect:

```
strings.OrderBy(w => w.StartsWith("the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? w.Substring(4).TrimStart() : w);

  elephant 
 dog 
The aardvark 
the bear 
The  cat
```

Handling leading spaces before the leading "the" looks correct

```
strings.OrderBy(w => w.TrimStart().StartsWith("the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? w.TrimStart().Substring(4).TrimStart() : w.TrimStart());
```

Gives:

```
The aardvark 
the bear 
The  cat 
 dog 
  elephant
```

But there may be other edge cases around null/empty/whitespace checking at multiple points...

Answer (score 1):

```
CaseStudies.OrderBy(a => a.Name.TrimStart().StartsWith("the ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? a.Name.TrimStart().Substring(4).TrimStart() : a.Name)
```

Comment: Please explains what **a.Name.Substring(4)** means

Comment: @SiddiqueMahsud It skips the first 4 characters.